# pandas list comprehension if statement

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I want to loop through a column in my dataframe such that if the word exist, then add to a new column the word.

## This is my data:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'title':pd.Series(['123','xyz']),
'question':pd.Series(["Hi i want to buy orange and pear", "How much is the banana?"])
 }
df =pd.DataFrame(d)
```

## df

```
                         question     title
0  Hi i want to buy orange and pear   123
1           How much is the banana?   xyz
```

## code:

```
#write to column if word exist:

fruit_list=['orange','pear','banana']
for i in fruit_list:
    df['fruit']=[i if i in qn for qn in df['question']]
```

## desired output:

```
                         question     title   fruit
0  Hi i want to buy orange and pear   123     orange
1  Hi i want to buy orange and pear   123     pear
2  How much is the banana?            xyz     banana
```

## error

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax at the 'for' word.
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you want is:

```
fruit_list=['orange','pear','banana']

df['fruit'] = [[f for f in fruit_list if f in qn] for qn in df['question']]
```

Comment: With that,  the output for the first line has 2 fruits in there but i want them as separate rows.

Comment: Ah I didn't read the question properly.  I don't know that there's a good way to flatmap a data frame that doesn't involve copying rows, so Asav's answer may be the way to go

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
input = [{"question" : "Hi i want to buy orange and pear", "title" : 123}
        , {"question" : "How much is the banana?", "title" : 456}]
list_size = len(input)

output = []

fruit_list=['orange','pear','banana']

for i in range(list_size):
    fruits = [f for f in fruit_list if f in input[i].get("question")]
    for f in fruits:
        if not input[i].get("fruit"):
            input[i]['fruit'] = f
        else:
            i = input[i].copy() # need to append a copy, otherwise it will just add references to the same dictionary over and over again
            i['fruit'] = f
            input.append(i) 
print (input)
```

If you don't want to create new object after modification then above code would work but if it's ok to create another object for output then code becomes more simpler.

```
input = [{"question" : "Hi i want to buy orange and pear", "title" : 123}
                     , {"question" : "How much is the banana?", "title" : 456}]
output = []
fruit_list=['orange','pear','banana']

for i in input:
    fruits = [f for f in fruit_list if f in i.get("question")]
    for f in fruits:
        i['fruit'] = f
        output.append(i.copy()) # need to append a copy, otherwise it will just add references to the same dictionary over and over again
print (output)
```

hope it helps

Comment: would you mind accepting the answer if it did solved the issue for you?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  For each row, it provides a list of matching words, and then expands the dataframe so that there is only one matched word per row.

```
fruit_list = ['orange', 'pear', 'banana']
df['word_match'] = df.question.str.findall(
    r'[\w]+').apply(set).apply(lambda my_set: list(my_set.intersection(fruit_list)))
>>> df
                           question title      word_match
0  Hi i want to buy orange and pear   123  [orange, pear]
1           How much is the banana?   xyz        [banana]

rows = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    [rows.append([row.question, row.title, word]) for word in row.word_match]
>>> pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df.columns)
                           question title word_match
0  Hi i want to buy orange and pear   123     orange
1  Hi i want to buy orange and pear   123       pear
2           How much is the banana?   xyz     banana
```